# Installing Remote Administration Tool on Ubuntu

Tags: remote

i want a R.A.T for Ubuntu 14.10. I don't know if there is any kind of RATs for Ubuntu and i've already searched it, but no results except fake RATs.
Which RAT do you prefer for Ubuntu 14.10 and how to install it?

EDIT:
Im looking for a RAT with GUI and i tried two RAT already. n00bRAT and Demonio, i can't install n00brat and Demonio is in spain :)

Please Help.

Comment: What are your requirements exactly? GUI/command line, interactive yes/no, management of large amounts of machines or just 1:1? etc. etc. Please also [edit] your question to include what you have tried already. It's hard to get a good answer without listing what you are looking for. SSH could be an answer here, but you might already have tried that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only that I know is discontinued, but works.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/demonio/
If you only want a shell, try SSH.

#### EDIT:

---

Have you tried [n00brat](https://code.google.com/p/n00brat/)?

Comment: I don't know how to install Demonio, the readme file is in spain and n00brat isn't working

Comment: @TobiasPetrus: You only need to use google translator and qt4 ;-)